# ClearCase Client Installation requires clearcase_albd service account password

Tags: clearcase

While installing ClearCase Client I want to avoid providing clearcase_albd sevice account password to the developers.
Is there any way this can be done so that end-users need not know clearcase_albd password?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done launching a s[ilent installation using a response file from a network share drive](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27017738) (ClearCase 7.1.x).

That shared drive is not accessible by the user, only by a special account that the support uses for the installation.

You find the same technique for ClearCase 8.x: "[Installing ClearCase silently using a response file](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_installing_silently_with_response_file.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F0-1-1-2-4-2)".

Comment: What about the Upgrade from 8.0.1.0 to 8.0.1.7 using Installation Manager? I see that Installation Manager is querying the IBM WEB Site first and then it installs the selected version. Any idea if UPGRADE can be done like the 8.x method?

Comment: @user3806728 it should be possible: The IM (Installation Manager) can be used in command-line, and a silent package update is therefore possible: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_running%20_im_silently11_rsar.htm